# CUDA to Metal Conversion. Is there an equivalent to CUDA Titan in Metal that will run real physics on the GPU?

Tags: software-development, gpu, physics

I'm converting a C++ app from CUDA to Metal. The App uses [Titan](https://jacobaustin123.github.io/Titan/classtitan_1_1_simulation.html) to model physics. Is there an equivalent to Titan in Metal that will run physics on the GPU using Metal? I could use SKPhysicsBody but I don't think that runs physics on the GPU. My project requires real physics as opposed to pseudo game-physics.